# Using CSS to dynamically control size of two inner divs

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I've got a div container that has some fixed size "pre" and "post" content, with the main content sandwiched in the middle - the main content basically consists of a label and a number.  Here's a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDU2V/2/) with sample (code also copied below - I added the colors just for visible contrast).

Wireframe mockups:

```
------------------------------------------
| A | Variable Sized Content | 123   | B |
------------------------------------------
```

`A` and `B` are the pre and post content; the text and number are meant to be variable sized, with the idea that if there's not enough room, the content will shrink and be truncated with ellipsis:

```
---------------------------------
| A | Variable Siz... | 123 | B |
---------------------------------
```

If there is a lot of room, the extra space goes between the number and `B`:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| A | Variable Sized Content | 123              | B |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

The way I've got it working right now is by having a resize listener on `outerDiv` in Javascript that sets the `max-width` of the `member-text` class.  This also manages the minimum size of the content div so that shrinking further will ellipse-out the number as well.

The problem I'm having is in trying to make this work **without** Javascript - having `max-width` constantly changing for all the elements is rather cludgy/slow (the sample only shows two items, but in production this is in a list of many items), and it makes the structure less portable for using as subcomponents of other widgets.  I can refactor it to work, but that'll take some time, and it seems the "more correct" solution is to just use CSS where possible.

The closest I got to simulating this was to set `max-width` for `member-text` to 100% and `max-width` for `member-token` to around 85%, which looks good for the outerDiv width range around the default (230-290ish), but beyond that it breaks down (too much/little spacing in the wrong parts).

**Edit:** I've also now tried divs with `display: table` (and `table-row`/`table-cell`, with `table-layout: fixed` on the root div - by specifying a width on all but one column, that column can be dynamically sized.  This would be useful if there was only one div that had variable sized content (the text), but in this case, there are two (the bubble text, represented by a number in the mockups), but this strategy doesn't seem to allow multiple dynamically sized columns.

**Which leads to my question(s) - is it even possible to do this sort of thing with just CSS? And if so, how?**  Even assuming the number is a fixed width to simplify the issue, this doesn't seem possible without Javascript...

Here's the code sample (simplified example to demo the issue)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="post-mark"></div>
  <div class="pre-mark"></div>
  <div class="member">
        <div class="member-token">
            <label class="member-text">Very Long Text Purple Monkey Dishwasher</label>
        </div>
        <div class="member-bubble">
            <span class="member-bubble-text">500</span>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="post-mark"></div>
  <div class="pre-mark"></div>
  <div class="member">
        <div class="member-token">
            <label class="member-text">Purple Monkey Dishwasher</label>
        </div>
        <div class="member-bubble">
            <span class="member-bubble-text">500</span>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outerDiv {
      width: 280px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: lightgrey;
  }

  .post-mark {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      margin-right: 8px;
      position: relative;
      width: 18px;
      float: right;
      background-color: cyan;
  }

  .pre-mark {
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: 4px;
      position: relative;
      width: 18px;
      float: left;
      background-color: pink;
  }

  .member {
      margin-left: 22px;
      height: 22px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      white-space: nowrap;
      background-color: cadetblue;
  }

  .member-token {
      float: left;
      height: 20px;
      margin-left: 2px;
      padding: 0 3px;
      background-color: darksalmon
  }

  .member-text {
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 20px;
      max-width: 193px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      background-color: goldenrod;
  }

  .member-bubble {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0 4px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: burlywood
  }

  .member-bubble-text {
      top: 4px;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: #F2F2F2;
      border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 14px;
      max-width: 100%;
      padding 0 4px;
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: top;
      color: #666666;
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: bold;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know tables should generally be avoided for non-tabular data, however, in this case I think it may be your best bet.

I was able to get your desired behavior with simple HTML/CSS by using a table.
The key trick here was having the variable sized content cell position: relative, and within it an absolutely positioned span pinned to all four corners so that it stretches.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="pre">
        A
    </td>
    <td class="shrinking">
        <span>
            Very Long Text Purple Monkey Dishwasher
        </span>
    </td>
    <td class="expanding">
        <span>500</span>
        <span class="post"> B</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    background: lightgrey;
    width:300px;
}
td {
    border: 1px red solid;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
td.pre {
    width: 25px;
    min-width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
td.shrinking {
    max-width: 280px;
    width: 280px;
    position: relative;
}
td.shrinking span {
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
td.expanding {
    min-width: 80px;
}
.post {
    float:right;
    border: 1px red solid;
    width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can see it in action here, http://jsfiddle.net/ijoukov/xMf8L/

Comment: Hm - it seems to do fine in Chrome, but it fails pretty horribly in Firefox (lots of overlapping text) and IE9 (no text in expanding area). The premise seems promising though...

Comment: Actually, in looking at this further, it completely depends on the text having a fixed max-width of around 280px (in the td.shrinking rule). The linked jsfiddle only looks like it works (and still only in Chrome) for the single data value - replacing the text in this area with different values causes it to fall apart.

Comment: Yes, you need some sort of max width on the text div.  Otherwise, I'm quite certain there's no way to make it stop growing once your text is fully shown, because I don't believe css can recognize when that happens.  You will almost certainly need some sort of Javascript to do what you want.  I'll look into the other browsers though, I'm surprised Firefox doesn't work.  Good luck, post your solution if you find one.

Comment: see my edit regarding `display: table` - it's another option I explored, but perhaps there's some tricks around there I'm not aware of?